# Getting an array of users that edited a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, mediawiki, mediawiki-api

I am working on a user script for a Wikia community ( http://c.wikia.com ) and I need to get array of users (and possibly revision IDs) of a page. I have come up with the following code but cannot seem to make it work. Any help would be appreciated.

Code:

```
var revisions = [];
$.getJSON('/api.php', {
    action: 'query',
    prop: 'revisions',
    titles: mw.config.get("wgPageName"),
    rvprop: 'user',
    rvlimit: '50',
    format: 'json'
}, function (result) {
    for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        var revision = result.query.pages.page[i].revisions.user;
        revisions.push(revision);
    }
    alert(revisions);
});
```

Comment: What's wrong with it?

Comment: What errors (if any) are you getting?

Comment: The issue is that it isn't returning anything, just blank.

Comment: sounds like a problem with api.php or the parameters you are sending it (or not sending it)

Comment: Nt your case, but those with access to the wiki configuration can jst use (and enable if disabled) action=credits. https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Parameters_to_index.php#credits

Answer (score 1):

The query result looks something like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "pages": {
      "421588": {
        "pageid": 421588,
        "ns": 0,
        "title": "Community Central",
        "revisions": [
          {
            "user": "Mhadick"
          },
          {
            "user": "Nblonkenfeld"
          },
          …
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  …
}
```

You'll notice that `pages` is an object with property named after the page id of the current page `"421588"` (judging from your code, you might be looking at the XML version of the response, you have to look at the JSON). To work with that, you can use something like:

```
var users = [];

$.getJSON('/api.php', {
    action: 'query',
    prop: 'revisions',
    titles: mw.config.get("wgPageName"),
    rvprop: 'user',
    rvlimit: '50',
    format: 'json'
}, function (result) {
    var revisions = result.query.pages[mw.config.get("wgArticleId")].revisions;

    $.each(revisions, function(key, revision) {
        users.push(revision.user);
    });

    alert(users);
});
```